# Instantiate and call a method in one line

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to instantiate a class and call one of its methods in one line? I hoped the following would work but it doesn't:

```
(new User())->get_name();
```

Comment: I hope not - better keep your code readable.

Comment: How about something like User::get_instance()->get_name()? Can something like that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. You could, however, create a static method returning a new instance. Something like:

```
class User {
    public static function create() {
        return new self();
    }
}

User::create()->get_name();
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this question is old but the replies can be misleading.

Since version 5.4 you can instantiate and call methods inline:

```
(new Foo())->bar();
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Link is dead, but there is now a one-line create and access example in the primary documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-193

Answer (score 2):

Nope, sorry, this unfortunately doesn't work in PHP. You could work around it by using a static factory method or something like that though.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you. It calls the function from the class not an object.

```
User::get_name();
```